# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `path` supplied to `Route`

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm providing a regular expression to a `react-router` Route like this:

```
    <Router>
      <Route path={/\/(?!path-to-exclude)/gi} component={Navbar}/>
      <Route path={/\/(?!path-to-exclude)/gi} component={ChatModal}/>
      ...
    </Router>
```

It's apparently working since these components are not shown when the route matches the regular expression, however I'm getting this warning in the console:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `path` supplied to `Route`.
    in Route (at App.js:45)
    in App (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at src/index.js:15)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.js:14)
    in Provider (at src/index.js:13)
```

Is there a proper way to provide a regular expression to a react-router path or to exclude certain matches in paths?

Comment: Those paths are not going to be used? If you are going to use them, you can play with the order of the `Route` to catch those excluded paths first.

Comment: @luckongas I want to hide those components only when the route matches. They're outside the`Switch` for that reason